# Swipe Gesture Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i wanted to swipe my image view but not swapped to left side.
i get image from frontcard array. and i wanted to display in imageview and swipe verticlally.

I tried this one

```
FrontsCards =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:9];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub1.png" atIndex:0];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub2.png" atIndex:1];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub3.png" atIndex:2];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub4.png" atIndex:3];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub5.png" atIndex:4];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub6.png" atIndex:5];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub7.png" atIndex:6];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub8.png" atIndex:7];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub9.png" atIndex:8];

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
    leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [ImgView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
    int m = 0;
    NSLog(@"Left Swipe");

    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSLog(@"%d",m);

    for(m=0; m<[delegate.FrontsCards count];m++) {
        int randIdx=arc4random()%[delegate.FrontsCards count];   // Randomly     shufffled
        ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        ImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[delegate.FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx]];

        NSLog(@"%d",m);
    }
}
```

images not swapped to imageview.
how to solve my problem help me out this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the console showing the logs from the leftSwipeHandle: method?

Comment: Is `leftSwipeHandle` method called, have you checked with break points

Comment: UIImageView will have userInteraction disabled by default, you need to set it to YES explicitly.

Comment: i do all this things but images sitll not displayed. and my leftSwipeHandle method called.

Comment: @JitendraDeore : What is the use of that for loop in `leftSwipeHandle`. You have 9 elements in the array and you are using random number for image, so finally last image will display in image view. So i dont think there is a need of that for loop.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create ImgView ?

Comment: adding it through xib

Comment: @NiravGadhiya is right... there is a no need of for loop inside **leftSwipeHandle** method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this one. Because by default image's user interaction is `NO`. So you need to set user interaction `YES`.

```
FrontsCards =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:9];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub1.png" atIndex:0];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub2.png" atIndex:1];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub3.png" atIndex:2];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub4.png" atIndex:3];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub5.png" atIndex:4];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub6.png" atIndex:5];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub7.png" atIndex:6];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub8.png" atIndex:7];
[FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub9.png" atIndex:8];

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
    leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [ImgView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];

    // --------------- Add this line here ------------
    ImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    int m = 0;
    NSLog(@"Left Swipe");

    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSLog(@"%d",m);

    for(m=0; m<[delegate.FrontsCards count];m++) {
        int randIdx=arc4random()%[delegate.FrontsCards count];   // Randomly     shufffled
        ImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[delegate.FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx]];
        NSLog(@"%d",m);
    }
}
```

Comment: ImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; Write this line in viewDidLoad not in this method - (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer. And see my edited answer

Comment: images not displayed when left swapped.

Comment: Check in for loop . What image name you are getting ?

Comment: NO i mean what you got by this line [delegate.FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx]

Comment: images displayed in nslog but imageview display onle one image not to swipe new image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29981/discussion-between-dharmbir-choudhary-and-jitendra-deore)

Answer (score 2):

**in .h file**

```
int imgCount;
```

**in .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
    leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [ImgView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];

    imgCount = 0;
}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    ImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[delegate.FrontsCards objectAtIndex:imgCount]];
    imgCount++;
    if (imgCount >= 9) {
       imgCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first part of the answer may be valid, but the use of imgCount is not valid and it removes the randomness.

Comment: yes, but no need to write for loop in leftSwipeHandle method as mentioned in question. so, i write this code... if this is work then Imodify some code...It is for checking purpose that image is change or not....

Comment: cloub1.png, cloub2.png all images are exist in resources or not?

Comment: all images are in resources.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[delegate.FrontsCards objectAtIndex:imgCount]);    can you give output for this line?

Comment: i will not get the exact counter value it will get 103

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29979/discussion-between-dharaparekh-and-jitendra-deore)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[ImgView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
//Add this
ImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` on `UIImageView`.

Comment: print image name [delegate.FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx] is it proper or blank?

Comment: what it prints?..[delegate.FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[ImgView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
ImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

`UIImageView` is disabled by default. You need to make it enabled.